# Best way to create new multi file wizard plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I want to create an eclipse plugin which appears in the "new" menu like "new class" (for example "new MyStructure").

The goal of this plugin is to ask a name and a folder where to place the generated content.

The generated content is created by copying an existing standard directory like the following (${dir} represents the selected directory in the wizard and ${name} the name asked in the wizard) :

```
$dir
    - ${name}.java
    - css
        - Default${name}Style.css
    - ${name}Editor.java
    - ${name}.config
```

each of this file is based on an existing file content, something like eclipse code template where I can specify dynamic ${name} and package.

How can I easily done this eclipse plugin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create an extension of `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` to create the wizard
2. Use the class `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DirectoryDialog` to let the user select a directory
3. Use an text field to let the user input the `${name}`
4. Use `java.io.*` to copy the files to the specified directory (or use `org.eclipse.core.resources` if you want to copy to the workspace)
5. Create an extension of `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` with `newWizardShortcut` to add the new wizard to the perspective you want to extend